# How to hide the resolved value of a variable in ksh?

Tags: shell, unix

I am currently stuck with a situation where i need to hide the resolved value of a variable, i.e., the value should not appear when the code runs in the debug mode i.e., ksh -x.

I have seen other threads on similar kind of problem but there, a way has been provided when the value is read from STDIN, with the help of read -s option. But i do not have to read the value from STDIN.

Kindly help me with this.

Thanks,
Amit

Answer (score 0):

When the field to be hidden is unique (something like a strong password), you can make a wrapper that changes the output of the script.
You should only take care for the special characters in the variable such as a slash. Try something like

```
mycode.sh 2>&1 | sed "s/${myvar}/xxxxxxxx/g"
```

When you use the variable on a few places only, a good alternative is testing the mode you are running in, and turn off the debug mode before using the variable (and turn on one line later).